# placing an Image between paragraphs dynamically using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to build a content management system but I am not able to find logic how to insert and retrieve contents with some Image insert the paragraphs. I have found some libraries that gives textarea extra functionality like adding Images between paragraphs but I don't know how I should save them  in the database and retrieve contents with images between paragraphs.

That being said, I know how to save images and words but separately. Someone with an ideas how this is done can help to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

This concept may address one aspect of what you're trying to achieve:

You can convert any image to [base64](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html.html) and embed it right into your html. You can also embed inline css into your html using the style attribute and float that image to the left or right side of a paragraph. Here's an example:

```html
<img style="float:right;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
<p>This paragraph is wrapping around an image (shown right) that is embedded into the html via base64. You can convert any image to base64 online.
<p>This could all be save into a database, and when rendered by a web browser, it would look about like how you see it here.</p>
<p>Good Luck!</p>
```

Link:
[Convert image to base64 online](https://www.base64-image.de/)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas and I have seen your message but without going far let's take an example when posting a question here on stack overflow. how are these question saved with their images in the back-end ?

Comment: The images you upload here, are put at a URL permanently at imgur.com. The only thing they're saving, in their database, is the markup that references the url of that image. This answer is just showing a way you could actually embed the image itself inside of the database with the HTML (instead of referencing a URL). I'm not saying it is a best practice, but thought you should know that it is possible.